# Basic program logic's in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, global-variables

I am trying to write a simple guessing program. The problem is when it is a wrong guess, it should prompt for another number.

Which is where, I need some help.

```
 var x;    
   x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);    
   var gx = prompt("Enter a number");    
     if(x == gx){    
     alert("Correct");    
     }    
     else{    
       for(i=0; i<=3; i++){    
       alert("Wrong");    
       }    
     }    
 alert("Over");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Paste your code into your question and remove the picture reference to it.

Comment: COde should not be an image, please paste code so it is selectable

Answer (score 2):

Try a while loop

```
var gx = null;
var answer = false;
while(!answer){
  if(gx!== null){
    alert('Wrong!');
  }
  gx = prompt('take a guess');
}
alert('You got it!');
```